# Replace multiple characters in string using dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, str-replace

I have some strings that have the following characters: `&`, `<`, and `>`. In the project I am working on, these are reserved characters and need to be escaped using `&amp;` for `&`, `&lt;` for `<`, etc. What is this best approach to this? Currently thinking of either multiple if statements that look for it one-by-one using str.replace() or somehow using a dictionary where the keys are the characters to be replaced and the values are what to replace them with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`html.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) function(`html` is part of python standard library) to replace the special characters `&`, `<` and `>` with `&amp;&lt;&gt;`

```
>>> import html
>>>
>>> html.escape("&<>")
'&amp;&lt;&gt;'
>>>
>>> help(html.escape)
Help on function escape in module html:

escape(s, quote=True)
    Replace special characters "&", "<" and ">" to HTML-safe sequences.
    If the optional flag quote is true (the default), the quotation mark
    characters, both double quote (") and single quote (') characters are also
    translated.
```